# For a triangle with the sides: $a=832, b=623, c=345$ find the angles.

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

For a triangle with the sides: $a=832, b=623, c=345$ find the angles $A$, $B$ and $C$ which are opposite to lengths sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ as shown below:

[image]

Here are the solutions I get on my attempt (in degrees, rounded to whole numbers):

$$
A=116
$$
$$
B=42
$$
$$
C=22
$$

Are they correct?

Comment: Ok, how did you arrive at these solutions?

Comment: Solve the triangle???? Are $a,b,c$ length of sides and $A,B,C$ the measure of the angles? You need to keep in mind that this website is international and notations are very different from place to place so many people might not understand your question. Please ensure that it is clear what you are asking, people don't want to guess the question.

Comment: In fact, what is your question? Checking you are correct?

Comment: @user88595 My apologies. Do the edits clear it up?

Comment: You can use the Law of Cosines to solve this and the Law of Sines to check it.

Comment: @user125736: I've edited it. This shows what you are looking for and explains which triangle you are talking about. Don't worry, we all make mistakes the first time, all that matters is that you learn and make a better question for next time.

Answer (score 0):

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos\gamma$$
Transform the equation so that  you have the values you know on one side, and *cos* on the other. Then apply the inverse function of *cos*.

If you are rounding the exact solutions, I would take 43 for B.